# MSGraph Calendar Events Multiple Notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Noticed that I am receiving multiple notifications when a calendar event is created or updated. For example, I created an event on Outlook calendar web client and invited some attendees. I received one notification with `changeType` as "created", followed by 4 notifications with `changeType` as "updated". What is the logic behind the notifications? There were no updates made to this event. All the notifications came within 1 or 2 seconds after the first "created" notification.

Answer (score 1):

The number of notifications depends on the number of objects your event action affects. For example creating a new meeting results in an update of the calendar folder object. Remember that you are not subscribed only to the event but the calendar, so your requirement from the API maybe a subset of what the API does

IMHO it is a redundant feature carried forward from EWS

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to know exactly what object changed? I see that the dataID (event ID) is the same for all the notifications. When creating the notification, I specify the resource as "me/events". Is this still subscribing to the calendar?

Comment: me/events is a super-set of me/calendar/events. The object changes I mentioned above are internal to exchange functionality for all practical purposes and hence the extra update notifications are redundant. You should design your application to treat these as duplicates. I am not associated with Microsoft and my understanding is based purely on years of using EWS and Graph push notifications. Please accept/upvote the answer if it addressed your question